# CAPTCHA is not showing on registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha, recaptcha

I have turned on the CAPTCHA for the register page on Magento 1.9 Community Edition.

But the text-box for the CAPTCHA don't show up. When I click register I got an error of 'Incorrect CAPTCHA'

Comment: have you added the captcha credentials??

Comment: no beacuse the CAPTCHA was not visible to me.

Comment: i am asking about `Google API website key` and `Google API website secret` in admin config

Comment: i m using magento's default CAPTCHA